# In Android how to display percentage in pie chart with achartengine

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart

I am using achartengine for displaying the pie chart and I have tried this :--

```
public class AChartEnginePieChartActivity extends Activity {   

private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };  

private static double[] VALUES = new double[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };  

private static String[] NAME_LIST = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };  

private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");  

private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();  

private GraphicalView mChartView;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.main);  

mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);  
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));  
mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);  
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);  
mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);  
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });  
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);  

for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {  
mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + VALUES[i], VALUES[i]);  
SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();  
renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);  
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);  
}  

if (mChartView != null) {  
mChartView.repaint();  
}  

}  


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override  
protected void onResume() {  
super.onResume();  
if (mChartView == null) {  
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);  
mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);  
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);  
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);  

mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();  

if (seriesSelection == null) {  
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
} else {  
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ (seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+1) + " was clicked" + " point value="+ seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  
}  
});  

mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {  
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override  
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {  
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();  
if (seriesSelection == null) {  
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
return false;   
} else {  
Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+ " was long pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
return true;         
}  
}  
});  
layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  
}  
else {  
mChartView.repaint();  
}  
}  
}
```

Here its displaying the pie chart [Like this picture](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PyywxSgVUcs/UUpC-1cmH_I/AAAAAAAAAGw/u980pKTf6LY/s1600/device-2013-03-21-041707.png)..But I want the value as percentage..
like A(10%) B(11%) in the picture..
How can I do that?????
please suggest me

Comment: hope this link will be help full for you https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: @ Hafiz.M.Usman this one is also good..is there any other example??

Comment: its the simplest one you have to try it it will be perfect for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope it will help to resolve your problem:-

```
mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + "(" + VALUES[i]+"%)", VALUES[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for Android, then `IValueFormatter` is now deprecated. You need to use `abstract class ValueFormatter`

```
public class MyValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
private final DecimalFormat mFormat;

public MyValueFormatter() {
    mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    return mFormat.format(value) + " %"; // e.g. append percentage sign
}
}
```

and then just use it by

```
data.setValueFormatter(MyValueFormatter())
```

where `data` is your `PieData`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `IValueFormatter`:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

private DecimalFormat mFormat;

public MyValueFormatter() {
    mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    // write your logic here
    return mFormat.format(value) + " %"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
}}
```

And next, set your formatter to the `ChartData` or `DataSet` object:

```
dataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

Remember this inner class just adds `%` to the end of your value.
For example if you want to add `$`, you should be using `$` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MPAndroidChart (Pie Chart) for Android, And you are looking for how to add the % symbol in a particular Pie chart Area then, try the below code it will solve your problem

```
public class MyValueFormatter extends PercentFormatter {
    DecimalFormat mFormat;
    PieChart mPieChart;

    public MyValueFormatter(DecimalFormat format, PieChart pieChart){
        mFormat = format;
        mPieChart = pieChart;
    }


    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return mFormat.format(value) + "%";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPieLabel(float value, PieEntry pieEntry) {
        if (mPieChart != null && mPieChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled()) {
            return getFormattedValue(value);
        } else {
            return mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And simply set this attribute in your pie chart

```
pieData.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(new DecimalFormat("###,###,###"), mPieChart));
```